# Remove page braek from PDF- DOMPDF or any PHP lib

Tags: php, dompdf

I am trying to remove a page break from a PDF file using `DOM PDF`.

I also tried to get page number and regenerate PDF File with custom page height.

Comment: To get help on SO you should provide details about what you have tried and the results you get, including any errors. For Dompdf it's important to see the source HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look: http://www.tcpdf.org

Everything You need is in examples - ease to write and advanced php pdf lib.

Custom header > https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_002.phps